# @Types and Typescript Virtual Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, typescript

@Types produces a correctly structured node_modules folder.

However, Visual Studio reports 205 build errors like the following:

Error TS2688 Cannot find type definition file for 'yauzl'. TypeScript Virtual Projects 1 Active.

These errors match up the list of dependent js libraries added to node_modules.

I believe these errors are 'saying' that the Typescript Virtual Projects tooling cannot find the d.ts declarations files for the 205 dependencies. Of course, there is no reason for those d.ts files to exist. So the answer is (again) how to configure ASP.NET 4 MVC 5 to recognize new Typescript features.

Please help me I'm falling...

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this has to do with the typeRoots setting. 
typeroots defines the scope within the node_modules folder were @types will be searched for.

The initial documentation I had found for typeRoots gave an example of two value settings for typeRoots: [ "node_modules/@types/","node_modules"], which seemed to make some sense.

But when I removed "node_modules" value, the error of the system searching for d.ts files for the dependent javascript libraries was avoided.

Therefore the answer is to understand that the scopes registered in typeRoots must be valid for d.ts files.